# How to compute the distance between two adjacent coordinates?

Tags: text-processing

Let's say I have a file containing 3 columns and arbitrary number of rows (lines). Each row corresponds to xyz coordinates.

```
1  2  3 
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12
...
```

How can I compute the distance between first and second coordinates, second and third coordinates, third and fourth coordinates, and so on?

This is what I have done. But I think it can be simpler:

```
a=`wc -l < oldfile`
for i in $(seq 2 $a); do
   j=$((i-1))
   sed -n "${j},${i} p" <oldfile
done > ala

split ala -l 2 ala.
for i in ala.??; do
   echo `cat $i`| awk '{printf  "%.10f \n", sqrt (($4-$1)^2 + ($5-$2)^2) + ($6-$3)^2}'
done > newfile
```

I welcome any answer. Since I am very new to linux programming, simple commands with `split`, `cat`, `echo` and/or `awk` will be highly appreciated :).

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "take out"? If you want to output only lines 2 and 3 of that file, you can simply do `sed -n 2,3p`

Comment: What I mean is I want to create multiple files in one go. I want to create a file containing line 1 and 2, another file containing line 2 and 3, yet another file containing line 3 and 4, and so on.

Comment: I'll call X-Y-problem here. Writing the data to separate files may be less useful, than doing the operations in one go and write the results only.

Comment: Can you say something about what you want to do to the data? Writing the rows in pairs to files seems like an unnecessary extra step if what you actually want to do is to apply some operation on the rows in pairs.

Comment: I just want to compute the 3D distance those two adjacent lines. Very simple math. 

I did think that it might be unnecessary to write the rows into separate files. But I don't know any other ways. Please check in the answer below to rate my own answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given the sample input you provided. Also add your code where you've attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: well, here's a great example of how people should just ask for clarification, vote to close as unclear etc. instead of writing answers based on guessing what an unclear question means, sigh ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following `awk` command will read blank-separated (x,y,z) coordinates from the lines of some file called `file`, and will compute the distance between each line.

```bash
awk '
NR > 1 { printf "%f\n", sqrt(($1-x)^2 + ($2-y)^2 + ($3-z)^2) }
       { x=$1; y=$2; z=$3 }' file
```

The `awk` command above will, for each line apart from the first, write the distance from the point given by the current line to that of the previous line.  The variables `x`, `y` and `z` will contain the coordinates of the previous line, which are updated after calculating and outputting the distance value.

With the input

```
7 4 3
17 6 2
-2 0 0
```

... this would produce

```
10.246951
20.024984
```

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question

Comment: @user19532602 please remember to tick the answer that best addresses your requirement. Maybe upvotr answers that are good, to. This is how you show your thanks in StackExchange sites

Comment: Oh yes, I did try to upvote and tick. However, since my reputation has not reached 15, the uptove and tick are not considered. Maybe their history are kept until I obtain 15 reputation.

Comment: @user19532602 As the person who posed the question, you have a special privilege that allows you to accept an answer.  This is not dependent on the amount of "reputation" you have.  In fact, I believe that you _did_ accept the answer at first, but then unaccepted it for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes you are right. Only the upvoting depends on reputation. Maybe yesterday I clicked the tick mark twice. Now it is really ticked. Thank you and sorry I am noob :)

Comment: @user19532602 Absolutely no worries. Be well.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Simplifying the problem to take the first six values (3-per-row):

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = words; for @a -> $x1,$y1,$z1,$x2,$y2,$z2 {  \
         say sqrt( ($x1 - $x2)**2 + ($y1 - $y2)**2 + ($z1 - $z2)**2) };'  

#OR

raku -e 'my @a = words; for @a -> \x1,\y1,\z1,\x2,\y2,\z2 {  \
         say sqrt( (x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2 ) };'
```

Raku allows sigil-less variables (second example), which some programmers find more readable. The file is read into the `@a` array, broken on whitespace-separated `words`. Six variables are declared (second example): `x1,y1,z1` and `x2,y2,z2`. The distance equation is performed as requested by the OP, and values returned.

[Note that sigil-less variables are declared with a leading backslash, but can be written without the backslash from then on. One caveat is that sigil-less variables are generally immutable (useful for declaring constants), see URL below for details].

Sample Input (simplified version):

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10  11  12
13  14  15
16  17  18
```

Sample Output (simplified version):

```
5.196152422706632
5.196152422706632
5.196152422706632
```

For the final version, all you need to do is instruct Raku to create an overlap when reading data into the `@a` array like so: `my @a=lines.rotor(2 => -1).words;`. Using example data graciously provided by @Kusalananda:

```bash
~$ cat file
7 4 3
17 6 2
-2 0 0

~$ raku -e 'my @a=lines.rotor(2 => -1).words; for @a -> \x1,\y1,\z1,\x2,\y2,\z2 {say sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)};'  file
10.246950765959598
20.024984394500787
```

[https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-\_(sigilless_variables)](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-%5C_(sigilless_variables))
https://docs.raku.org/routine/rotor
https://raku.org

Comment: Thank you. Raku seems promising. But I still prefer the awk.

Comment: You might see a significant advantage using Raku if your matrix calculations become more challenging. Raku offers a number of matrix modules which can be called in a script, or even at the command line, simplifying you final code. See: https://github.com/pierre-vigier/Perl6-Math-Matrix or https://github.com/frithnanth/raku-Math-Libgsl-Matrix . The second module is an interface to vector/matrix functions of the GNU Scientific Library: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by 'take out': is it 'single out', or 'remove'? Normally I'd think of the latter, but your PS seems to indicate the former?

Assuming the former, you can do this in the shell:

```
# index of first row to print
n=3
tail -n +${n} <filename> | head -n 2
```

With the given n=3, this will print the third and fourth line.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you meant, I came with this solution to compute 6D distance of each row.

awk file dist.awk

```
function memorize() 
{ for(i=1;i<=6;i++) previous[i]=$i ;}

NR>1 {
   s=0 ;
   for(i=1;i<=6;i++) s+=($i-previous[i])**2 ;
   printf "dist=%f\n",sqrt(s) ;
}
{ 
  memorize() ;
  print ; 
}
```

- many prefer the use of `1` instead of `print`

Strangely with your data, I got folowwing result.

```
awk -f dist.awk  original.data
1  2  3  4  5  6
dist=14.696938
7  8  9  10 11 12
dist=14.696938
13 14 15 16 17 18
dist=14.696938
19 20 21 22 23 24
```

(points are aligned in a 6 dimension space, distance in sqrt(36*6) )

the point is awk, can remember previous row, and do compute on them.